# How do I handle NHibernate throwing a `NonUniqueObjectReferenceException` when I update an entity?

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate

I use `ISession.Query<T>().ToList()` to acquire a list of objects, add them to a ComboBox so the user can browse all the objects, and then I edit one of these and call `ISession.Update()` with that object. However this throws a `NonUniqueObjectReferenceException`.

Why does this happen and what approach should I use to avoid/fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update method as stated by Denis is used for the persistance of detached objects.This exception is thrown probably because you are trying to use `Update()` on those objects you probably already have in the session. You should use a transaction or `Flush()` in order to update your objects, if you already do so; deleting `session.Update()` from your code should do it.

Here is the appropriate part in the [NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating).

Answer (score 2):

### Problem explanation

When you load an entity, `Session` keeps track of the database's primary key for the entity as well as the entity's object `reference` (location in memory) - for the duration of the `Session`.

The `NonUniqueObjectReferenceException` is thrown if you attempt to persist an entity that has the same primary key but a different object `reference` as an already loaded entity for this `Session`.

In other words the `Session` is telling you, "I have an entity in memory with the same primary key as the entity you are trying to persist, but the object `reference` of my copy doesn't match your copy."

### Problem example

1. Open a `Session` (*#1*).
2. Load the entity (*object reference = **A**, primary key in database = **1***).
3. Close the `Session`.
4. Open a new `Session` (*#2*).
5. Load the same entity again (this time, *object reference = **B**, primary key in database = **1***).
6. Change a property on object A and persist it inside `Session` #2.
7. `NonUniqueObjectReferenceException` will be thrown.

It's worth noting that this exception will be thrown, even if object A is simply part of a larger object graph that is being persisted in session #2 (even if object A didn't change).

It's also worth noting that you can load an entity directly (`Session.Load`, `Session.Get`, `Session.QueryOver`, etc) or indirectly (with a query that doesn't return the object, but causes the object to be loaded into memory).  The `NonUniqueObjectReferenceException` can be thrown for both a directly or in-directly loaded entity.

**Important note:** This problem can be caused in other ways, for example it can be caused with a single `Session` if you load and then clone an entity and then use this clone to persist some changes using the `Session`.  Reason being, the clone's object `reference` would differ from the original entity.

### Solution explanation

There is a method called `Merge` on the `Session` object:

`object Session.Merge(object obj)`

`Merge` will take an entity and, using the entity's primary key, retrieve the already loaded version of this entity from the current `Session`.  It will also update the properties of the `Session`'s already loaded entity if they differ from the entity you have just passed.

This method does **not** change the entity that you pass in, but instead returns a different object which you should use.

One last note about `Merge` is that if the `Session` you are in doesn't have a loaded copy of this entity in memory, `Merge` will go ahead and load the entity from the database before performing it's usual merging functionality.

### Solution example

```
// using the example above, we are at the beginning of step 6 inside session #2
// we have 2 important objects = ISession sessionTwo, Option objectA.
// Option is an entity defined by you, it is not part of NH.

objectA.SomeProperty = "blah";
var optionFromSessionTwo = (Option) sessionTwo.Merge(objectA);

// this will not throw and it will persist the changes to objectA
sessionTwo.Flush();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation on:

- How to use NHibernate on Winforms
- What "Update" means.

The quick fix is: Don't call `session.Update()`, just call `session.Flush()` so the changes are reflected to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

`session.Update()` doesn't update the entity, session does that transparently. Update and Save methods aren't related to INSERT and UPDATE, instead, `Save()` makes transient object persistent, where `Update()` makes detached object persisted.